# add_filter only for front office

Tags: php

I have those lines in my functions.php to modify some menus in the front office of my site :

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','decorate_mobile_menu' );
function decorate_mobile_menu($item) {
    if ( strpos($item->title, 'SHIPPING') !== false) {  
        $split = explode(" IN ", $item->title);     
        $item->title = '<span class="shipping-menu-item">' . $split[0] . ' IN </span>';
        $item->title .= '<br/>';
        $item->title .= '<span class="shipping-menu-item">' . $split[1] . '</span>';
    }   
    return $item;
}
```

but everytime I "save" the corresponding menu in the back office, it runs this function again and the html gets crazy in the menu title :

```
<span class="shipping-menu-item"><span class="shipping-menu-item"><span class="shipping-menu-item"><span class="shipping-menu-item"><span class="shipping-menu-item">FREE SHIPPING IN </span><br/><span class="shipping-menu-item"></span><br/><span class="shipping-menu-item"></span><br/><span class="shipping-menu-item"></span><br/><span class="shipping-menu-item"></span><br/><span class="shipping-menu-item"><br/>EUROPE FROM 150€</span></span></span></span></span>
```

Can you help me clean this function to only act on front office ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it all in an `! is_admin()` check:

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','decorate_mobile_menu' );
function decorate_mobile_menu($item) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( strpos($item->title, 'SHIPPING') !== false) {  
            $split = explode(" IN ", $item->title);     
            $item->title = '<span class="shipping-menu-item">' . $split[0] . ' IN </span>';
            $item->title .= '<br/>';
            $item->title .= '<span class="shipping-menu-item">' . $split[1] . '</span>';
        }
    }

    return $item;
}
```

`is_admin()` returns `false` if you're viewing the front-end and `true` if you're viewing the admin area.